# Liferay 6.1 DynamicQuery - Complex Queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql, liferay, dynamicquery

I have an entity named `DistributedLock` :

```
<entity name="DistributedLock" local-service="true" remote-service="false">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="lockId" type="long" primary="true"/>

    <!-- Other fields -->

    <column name="ownerId" type="long"/>
    <column name="createDate" type="long"/>
    <column name="heartBeatInterval" type="long"/>
    <column name="lastHeartBeat" type="long"/>
    <column name="refCount" type="int"/>
    <column name="endDate" type="long"/> <!-- optional -->
    <column name="context" type="int"/> <!-- optional -->
    <column name="state" type="int"/> <!-- optional -->

</entity>
```

In order to remove dead locks, I need to run this query :

```
DELETE FROM distributed_lock WHERE `lastHearBeat` < ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000) - `heartBeatInterval` - 2000;
```

How can I execute such a query using `DynamicQuery`?
Is there any better option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it might be helpful to check ProjectionFactory https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1936351